# Creating a PHP CMS with an entry backup/restore option

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, backup, restore

I've been working on a CMS and wanted to add a backup/restore function.  I want it to backup a saved entry every other time it is edited so that if a client makes a change they are unhappy with or screws something up they can go back and choose a previous state to restore from.

The problem I'm having is trying to wrap my head around the concept of coding this functionality.  I have created a new table called "backup" with the fields "ID, date, time, pageName, and pageContent" but going on from there I find myself stuck.

Would I add on to my edit script a new query that saves a duplicate to the backup table? And how could I get it to only backup every few saved edits?

Here I have my save edit query, if it helps any.  Thanks in advance! :)

```
<?php
        $_POST['entry'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['entry']);
        $sql="update pageEntry set entry=\"$_POST[entry]\", pageName=\"$_POST[pageName]\" where id=\"$_POST[id]\"";       
        $result=mysql_query($sql)or die('Bad Query');
            echo "<div id='edit2'>The file has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory<br /></div>";  
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version control at the table level is usually done by adding a `version` column to your existing table. So if you had a `posts` table you would add a version column with a simple int or date value. Every time a post is edited a new record is inserted and the version number bumped. You can reference this version number in another table or have an additional `active` field to denote which post is the latest/active.

If you're talking about rolling back the database I would use the `mysqldump` command to dump and `mysql` to restore.